# Why can't using "await" for each mapped element in an array of promises be used instead of "promise.all"?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, equivalence

I have an array of fetch API calls that have been resolved as shown below:

```
let results = await Promise.all(promises);
```

I'm trying to get the result of each resolved fetch API call in the array. I tried console logging the results expecting the resolved responses

```
const newStuff = await results.map(async (response) => {
  try {
    const recipeDetail = await response.json();
    return recipeDetail;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error1: ", err);
  }
})

console.log(newStuff);
```

But I get back an array of pending promises.

However this below seems to work.

```
const newStuff = await Promise.all(results.map(async response => {
  let recipeDetail = await response.json();
  return recipeDetail;
}));

console.log(newStuff);
```

Why does the second example work when the first one doesn't?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `.map()` still returns an array (of promises), and you cannot `await` that.

Comment: FYI, you can replace `let recipeDetail = await response.json();
  return recipeDetail;` with `return response.json()` since either way you're returning a promise that resolves to `recipeDetail` and the second way is less code.  And, the `.map()` is not promise aware so it doesn't pause for your `await` and thus that `await` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an `async` function always returns a promise.

In your version that doesn't work, you're `await`ing the result of `map`, but there's no reason to do that, because `map` returns an array, not a promise. The array contains the promises from the calls to the `async` callback you provided `map`, but they're still pending since nothing has waited for them to settle (`map` knows nothing about promises). Your code within the `async` callback waits for the promises from `fetch` to settle before settling the `async` callback's promise, but nothing waits for the promise from the `async` callbacks to setting.

That's the purpose of `Promise.all`: It waits for the promises to settle and fulfills its promise with an array of the fulfillment values (not an array of promises).